# React Native: Customizing TouchableOpacity Animation Speed

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

According to the `TouchableOpacity` [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html), there is an `activeOpacity` prop to change the end opacity level and there is a `setOpacityTo` function to animate the component to any opacity level. There doesn't seem to be anything about changing how fast the animation should take.

How would I go about changing the animation speed? Is there a props for this? Do I need to make my own custom `Animated.View`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That'd be the duration part of the method...

```
setOpacityTo(value: number, duration: number)
```

React-native is using setOpacityTo in the background to animate the opacity using the [`setNativeProps with TouchableOpacity`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b983de9c5460e24c95a9a67f02695cd1c5f31bc5/docs/direct-manipulation.md).

```
setOpacityTo(value) {
  // Redacted: animation related code
  this.refs[CHILD_REF].setNativeProps({
    opacity: value
  });
},
```

So, it looks like you can also just create your own Animated event if you wanted to. Here's [how touchable opacity uses `setOpacityTo`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c1223c553004a7628e22555d0ebac40581cba261/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity.js#L168-L178), making sure to set the `useNativeDriver` to `true`.

```
  setOpacityTo: function(value: number, duration: number) {
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.anim,
      {
        toValue: value,
        duration: duration,
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.quad),
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }
    ).start();
  },
```

Comment: Do you know how i would go about utilizing `setOpacityTo` to override the default animation when a `TouchableOpacity` is pressed?

Comment: @GabrielWest I've updated my answer with a few more tidbits that should set you on the right path.

Comment: Where to put setOpacityTo function @ChrisGeirman? And will it be called automatically by <TouchableOpacity />?

Comment: @JeafGilbert you would run this inside the method handling your onPress event