# React-Native Touchableopacity not wrapping properly

Tags: css, react-native

I'm rendering flatlist, and there is images which I render depending on the index.

So it looks like this: https://ibb.co/ep2zye

I'm rendering the left side of the flatlist like this:

```
if(index % 2 == 0){

            return {
                marginTop: -SCREEN_WIDTH/12 + -(index-2)*SCREEN_WIDTH/20,
                marginRight: SCREEN_WIDTH / 35,
                marginLeft: SCREEN_WIDTH / 35,
                margin: SCREEN_WIDTH / 50,
                width: this.width,
                height: this.height,
                opacity: this.state.opacity,
                borderRadius: SCREEN_WIDTH / 36,
            }
        }
```

And render looks like this:

```
return (
            <Animated.View pointerEvents={this.state.pointer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.captureAnimation.bind(this, item, index)} style={{backgroundColor: 'darkred'}}>
                    <AnimatedImage source={{uri: 'http://' + item.info.picture_path}} style={this.renderStyle(index)}/>
                    <View style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: SCREEN_WIDTH/20, left: SCREEN_WIDTH/24, width: '80%'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: SCREEN_WIDTH / 27, color: '#ffffff',fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.info.title} </Text>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: SCREEN_WIDTH / 42, color: '#ffffff',fontWeight: 'bold'}}> {item.date} </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
        );
```

So I dont understand why, touchable opacity is not wrapping the all image, instead of wrapping part of it? Even I do marginTop, touchableopacity should be wrapping it no? Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: setOpacityTo  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318861/react-native-customizing-touchableopacity-animation-speed

Comment: no I dont mean for animation actually. My question why the touchableopacity area gets smaller if its wrapping the imagine all the time?

Comment: +++ no comments? no solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by diving the full array into 2, then render each of them in left and right side. Yeah now it wraps at it should be but it is still not explaining why it didnt work in example which I showed..